# Can't get googletest running with ubuntu (linker errors)

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, eclipse-cdt, googletest

I've built googletest using make under linux, the resulting files are libgtest.a libgtest_main.a.

I referenced the include files from my application and added the following lib dependencies (in the given order):

```
-lgtest
-lpthread
```

However I get the following two linker errors when I try to compile:

```
more undefined references to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, testing::internal::String const&, testing::internal::String const&, bool)

undefined reference to `testing::internal::String::ShowCStringQuoted(char const*)
```

From what I've seen within the googletest source, the EqFailure function is directly implemented within gtest.cc. I don't understand why I should get a linker error here, the other definitions from googletest could obviously also be found (if I remove -lgtest, I get alot of more linker errors).

What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have installed other version of `Google C++ Testing Framework` on your system?

Comment: I had the libs within /usr/lib, I removed anything from googletest as I want to link googletest from a project-internal externals-folder. I checked whether the linker knows the libs via ldconfig -v | grep gtest, nothing is found. Still, I get the linker error on EqFailure.

Comment: `I removed anything` - What about includes (`/usr/include/gtest`)? Do you remove it? Also, can you share compile options (or build script) and project structure?

Comment: Do you use `google mock` or have it is installed on your system? Some times source of trouble is different versions of `google test` which provided with `google mock` and `google test` which used inside project.

Comment: I solved it now. Instead of downloading the source and compile it using make, I followed these instructions on using cmake: http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/ - now everything works, though it had been interesting to actually know what exactly caused the issue. Thank you for all your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do not accidentally mix your own gtest and the one shipped with ubuntu.

I use cmake to build and got the same errors due to cmake opting for /usr/include over my own custom built version (which is what I linked with).